# Higher quotation marks in equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, quotation

I want to use quotation marks in equations (using \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}) and I want them to be adapted to the height of the text in between. Something like:

```
\begin{equation}
    x = \left''\frac12\right``
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
    x = \Big{''}\frac12\Big{``}
\end{equation}
```

But none of these two, not any other I could attempt worked like I wanted.

Please, if someone can help.

Answer (score 3):

You raise quotes the required amount, but never lower them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathquotes}{m}{% #1 = subformula to be quoted
  {\mathpalette\mathquotes@{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\mathquotes@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\normalfont``}%
  \ifdim\ht\tw@>\ht\z@
    \dimen@=0pt
  \else
    \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\z@-\ht\tw@\relax
  \fi
  \raisebox{\dimen@}{\normalfont``}\box\z@\raisebox{\dimen@}{\normalfont''}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\mathquotes{a}+\mathquotes{\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version where `\mathquotes*` uses single quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\mathquotes}{sm}{{% #2 = subformula to be quoted
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \mathpalette\mathquotes@{{`}{#2}{'}}%
  }{%
    \mathpalette\mathquotes@{{``}{#2}{''}}%
  }%
}}

\newcommand{\mathquotes@}[2]{\mathquotes@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\mathquotes@@}[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\normalfont#2}%
  \ifdim\ht\tw@>\ht\z@
    \dimen@=0pt
  \else
    \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\z@-\ht\tw@\relax
  \fi
  \raisebox{\dimen@}{\normalfont#2}\box\z@\raisebox{\dimen@}{\normalfont#4}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\mathquotes{a}+\mathquotes{\frac{1}{2}}+\mathquotes*{A}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Quotation marks are not delimiters so you can't use `\left...\right` or `\Big` and friends.
And these only work on single characters, which `''` is not.

This solution will raise the quotation marks to the height of the fraction:

[image: raised quotation marks]

```latex
\catcode`\@=11
% \raisearound{<left material>}{<right material>}{<center material>}
\def\raisearound#1#2#3{\mathpalette\raisearoundA{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\def\raisearoundA#1#2{\raisearoundB#1#2}
\def\raisearoundB#1#2#3#4{{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
    \setbox1=\hbox{#3}%
    \setbox2=\hbox{$\m@th#1#4$}%
    \raise\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0\relax\box0%
    \copy2%
    \raise\dimexpr\ht2-\ht1\relax\box1%
}}
\catcode`\@=12

$A+\raisearound{``}{''}{\frac12}+B$

$\displaystyle A+\raisearound{``}{''}{\frac12}+B$
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D